# Is it possible to generate RSA key without pass phrase?

Tags: apache-2.2, https, openssl, passphrase

I'm working with Apache2 and Passenger for a Rails project. 
I would like to create a self-signed [SSL Certificate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/ssl/ssl_faq.html) for testing purposes.

```
sudo openssl rsa -des3 -in server.key -out server.key.new
```

When i enter the above command, it says

```
writing RSA key
Enter PEM pass phrase:
```

If i do not enter the pass phrse, im getting the below error

```
unable to write key
3079317228:error:28069065:lib(40):UI_set_result:result too small:ui_lib.c:869:Yo
u must type in 4 to 1024 characters
3079317228:error:0906406D:PEM routines:PEM_def_callback:problems getting passwor
d:pem_lib.c:111:
3079317228:error:0906906F:PEM routines:PEM_ASN1_write_bio:read key:pem_lib.c:382
```

Is it possible to generate a RSA key without giving `pass phrase`, since I am not sure how the `/etc/init.d/httpd` script will start the HTTP server without human intervention (i.e. If I give a 4 character pass phrase, it expects me to provide this while starting the Apache HTTP server).

Comment: Your command line tells `openssl` to encrypt an existing key. That sounds like something other than what you want.

Comment: Apache httpd _can_ be configured to obtain the privatekey passphrase(s) noninteractively; see the doc for mod_ssl, or in many cases comments in the provided/packaged config file(s). However, this is usually no more secure than just leaving the privatekey unencrypted, which is simpler.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

If you are generating a self signed cert, you can do both the key and cert in one command like so:

```
openssl req  -nodes -new -x509  -keyout server.key -out server.cert
```

Oh, and what @MadHatter said in [his answer](https://serverfault.com/a/366373) about omitting the `-des3` flag.

Comment: The nodes directive is why I'm here.
(No DES encryption of private key)

Comment: If you want it to expire after 10 years, set `-days 3650`

Answer (score 62):

Leave off the `-des3` flag, which is an instruction to openssl to encrypt server.key.new (which, incidentally, isn't a new key at all - it's exactly the same as server.key, only with the passphrase changed/stripped off).

Answer (score 44):

The `openssl req` command from the [answer by @Tom](https://serverfault.com/a/366374) is correct to create a self-signed certificate in `server.cert` incl. a password-less RSA private key in `server.key`:

```
openssl req -nodes -new -x509 -keyout server.key -out server.cert
```

**Here is how it works.** Omitting `-des3` as in the [answer by @MadHatter](https://serverfault.com/a/366373) is not enough in this case to create a private key without passphrase. It *is* enough for this purpose in the `openssl rsa` ("convert a private key") command referred to by @MadHatter and the `openssl genrsa` ("create a private key") command. Just not for for the `openssl req` command here. We additionally need `-nodes` ("No DES encryption of `server.key` please!").

Answer (score 39):

Use the `-nodes` parameter, if this option is specified then the private key will not be encrypted, e.g.:

```
openssl \
    req \
    -nodes \
    -newkey rsa:2048 \
    -keyout www.example.com.key \
    -out www.example.com.csr \
    -subj "/C=DE/ST=NRW/L=Berlin/O=My Inc/OU=DevOps/CN=www.example.com/emailAddress=dev@www.example.com"
```

Answer (score 16):

Adding `-nodes` to the 'openssl req' allows an unencrypted (no passphrase) private key to be generated from the 'openssl req' command.

The `-nodes` flag means "No DES": i.e., not encrypting the private key.

Comment: This is exactly the right answer.  The -nodes flag means "No DES": ie., no encrypting the private key.

Answer (score 14):

Just run it again through openssl

first generate the key with the passphrase

then `openssl rsa -in server.key -out server.key`

Comment: This is not working on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I downvoted because this answer is not what was asked, also the command requires an input and doesn't generate a key.

Comment: The user already demonstrated they know how to generate a key.
This answer builds on that knowledge, and I suggest to take the newly generated key and pass it again through `openssl` 

Hence achieving the goal of what was asked: generating a key without a pass phrase.

Comment: Works for me, `openssl` on Windows 10 from GitBash. Thanks for info.

Comment: cool it worked for my self signed cert

Comment: Not sure why one would suggest encrypting and decrypting instead of just not encrypting it in the first place.  Adding `-nodes` parameter is the more correct answer.

Comment: This is not wrong though, but you may also need to pass the current password via `-passin pass:PASSWORD` if used in non interactive mode

Answer (score 5):

Use the next command to generate password-less private key file with **NO encryption**. The last parameter is the size of the private key.

```
openssl genrsa -out my-passless-private.key 4096
```

Comment: This is NOT password-less. It is completely and entirely password-ful.

Comment: I was experimenting with position of the parameters. It is now OK. I changed the places of last two parameters and tested the command.

Comment: Now it produces an _unencrypted_ file. Options after the (only) positional argument are ignored. Look at the file; it's not encrypted. Replace `4096 -des3` with `4096 -sillywombat` and it still works and produces the same format, still unencrypted (but a different key value of course). There is no way to have a passwordless encrypted privatekey file, and correct solutions for a passwordless unencrypted file were given six years ago.

Comment: You are right. @dave_thompson_085. The last parameter doesn't any affect on the command. I updated my answer. It generate none encrypted base64 encoded and not password protected private key file.

Answer (score 0):

To generate PEM certificate without passphrase:

`openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 10000 -nodes`

Answer (score -1):

To generate a self signed cert for testing:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem \
-days 365 -sha256
```

Then remove the password from the key via

```
openssl rsa -in key.pem -out nopass.pem
```

This answers is from: https://actix.rs/docs/server/. This answer completes https://serverfault.com/a/662445/113360 above with a preceding step.

Comment: Or simpler use `-nodes` on `req -newkey` as was explained on multiple answers many many years ago. This not only does not add any positive value, it has _negative_ value.