# How can I create a self-signed certificate that works with the browser?

Tags: openssl, certificate, localhost

I have been trying to create a self-signed certificate.  The Firefox browser says the certificate is "not secure."

I created the certificate following this SO explaination: [Is it possible to generate RSA key without pass phrase?](https://serverfault.com/questions/366372/is-it-possible-to-generate-rsa-key-without-pass-phrase)

I entered the certificate into the mmc Microsoft Trust Store in the system and I can see the certificate I created by viewing 'more information' about the certificate.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by prefixing the package.json "start" script with "set cross-env..." now I have a valid, secure SSL localhost server.

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "start":"set cross-env HTTPS=true SSL_CRT_FILE=<path to:>server.cert SSL_KEY_FILE=<path to:>server.key && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```